# Viewable area in an HTML email

Tags: html, css, email

Potentially a topic for debate (or not) and I've searched and searched but not found anything. I code quite a lot of HTML emails (for my sins) and am surprised that this debate has only just come up but is there any way of determining where the "fold" would be in an HTML email?

I've thought about this quite a bit and of course it depends on lots of things such as:

> - How the user has setup their viewing panes (if using Outlook)
> - Screen resolution
> - What email client they are using

So I may have really answered my own question but I hope this is open for debate. Is there any "best practice" guidelines? I.e. maximum width (I try and keep emails below 600 and below) and of course the things I listed above. I've looked at the usual sites, MailChimp, Campaign Monitor etc to no avail!

I would be interested to hear your thoughts/comments/suggestions.

Thanks

Kiz

Comment: @Raoul — the line under which no content can be seen without scrolling (or resizing the viewing pane/window). It is a designer thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For HTML documents, you'd need to look into JavaScript code to check window dimensions. Alas, most e-mail clients disallow JS in incoming mail, so this will be extremely unreliable.

Aside from this, I don't think there's a way to do this: I've seen so many configurations that I think any size is possible.

Comment: Great thanks for this. I thought as much, but just wanted to ask in case there was any form of "best practice"